# Select max date and the date before

Tags: c#, datetime, maxdate

I have a data table which is updated every day except Saturday and Sunday.
The problem lies in so that when I retrieve data with max (date) and max (date) -1

But it fails when I try to retrieve data for today (Monday) and yesterday (Sunday) when max (date) -1 does not exist.

the data can be updated on Saturday and Sunday, but since it's exchange rate I update.
Will it give the same exchange rates Friday, Saturday and Sunday.

This is one way to solve the problem this way, but there is a better

```
string weekend = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
if (weekend == "Monday")
{
select ***** where max(date)-3 from *****
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some other options which work with an arbitrary target_date as well.

If you only have one record for each date,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date<=target_date ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2
```

If you have many records per date,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date IN (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM table WHERE date<=target_date ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2)
```

You could also use the date/time functions of your database to check for Monday, of course.

Comment: @Sigenstroem - But SELECT TOP x... would work as Dark Falcon has suggested.

Comment: Yes it works, it is also the approach I used to get it to work.
So thank you for the answers.!

Answer (score 1):

You can select the newest record that is at least one day old. Then the weekend isn't a special case.

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively trying to find the second highest date in a dataset.

Find the highest date in the data. Find values less than this, limit the results to 1 and you have the previous day in the dataset.

Any other method will fail on other days when rates are not updated, e.g. christmas.

Answer (score 0):

hmm you might need som more details on the string

The sql string is

SELECT m.Navn, m.Beskrivelse, p_idag.Points AS Points_idag, p_igaar.Points AS Points_igaar FROM medlem m LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM point WHERE Datoen = '06-09-2010') AS p_idag ON m.Navn = p_idag.Navn LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM point WHERE Datoen = '06-08-2010') AS p_igaar ON m.Navn = p_igaar.Navn ORDER BY m.Navn;

The first date is selected by the user, the next date that date -1 day or -3

Answer (score 0):

An easy way that works for me is:

select * from yourtable where date=(select max(date) from yourtable
where date < (select max(date) from yourtable))

Not sure how efficient it is